# Unreachable statement is a kind of error instead of warning in Java?

Tags: java, exception

In the getUsers method, it invokes an RestTemplate with remote api service. In the code, I want to mock that it throws exception. Then I hard code with `throw new Exception("read failed")`.

I know that the code below 'throws' will not be reachable. But I guess this should be only a warning in Intellij idea as the same as VisualStuido does with C#. But here it is an compile error.

Is there any way to suppress this compile error? Because I want to mock an exception here. Thanks.

Edit: 
Thanks all you guys! Yes, I am trying to insert some temporary debug code, not production code. I will remove the "throws" code once my debug is done.

[image]

Comment: so, just throw that exception and either delete, or comment out, all the other code

Comment: First of all, you should "share" the code as text, not as a picture (I know it's easier for you, but not for us...). Secondly, as you mentioned, you want to mock REST template, so mock it, why are you changing the code you do not want to touch...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unreachable code is a compilation error in Java, not just a warning. The code inspection does not "look" into conditionals, so you can simply do the following:

```
if (true)
  throw new MyException();
```

Comment: Huh, I always assumed the compiler wouldn't be fooled by a constant like that, but I just checked and it is.

Comment: how could throwing an exception under a dummy condition be justifiable?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - My impression is that the OP's inserting temporary debug code, not production code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My gut feeling is that it relates to generating valid (or maybe just *better*) bytecode. With an unconditional block, you'd need to have a `athrow` instruction (which alters the stack) followed by additional uncallable instructions. How should the compiler handle that? If the programmer inserts a conditional block themselves, no instructions need follow `athrow`, you can just have another separate path ending in `return` (or `_return`). So I don't think the compiler is *fooled* so much as it silently tolerates this "pattern".

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to suppress this compile error?

No. You can remove these 7 lines or comment them out. An exception is thrown unconditionally so there is no way the code below will ever be executed.

I am strongly against introducing a dummy condition to trick the compiler. You can fool the compiler, but you can't fool the developers that will be maintaining the codebase after you.

Answer (score 2):

No because it's compiler error - use dummy condition like

```
if(true) {
    throw new Exception("read failed");
}
```

but also consider mocking this method using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) or some dummy mock implementation - you will be able then to create proper unit test - such "testing" is rather bad idea and will not help you in the future (just imagine adding such lines every time you will change something and need to test again)

Comment: how could throwing an exception under a dummy condition be justifiable?

Comment: It cannot, I extended my answer

Answer (score 2):

Misconception: it is an error, and that is simply what the Java language spec wants it to be, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21):

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.

And you are going down the wrong rabbit hole: you shouldn't try to work around this "warning".  When your production code has to throw that exception, then there is **zero** sense in having other code follow that `throws` statement in your production code.

If you want to do some sort of mocking, all of that should happen in your "test" code base.

In other words: to enable yourself to test that catch block, what you could do: **extract** the part in the try block in a class of its own. Then pass a mocked instance of that class to your production code, and have that mock throw when calling a method on it.

Sometimes it is pragmatic to make slight changes to production code for testability (for example to make methods *not* private, to allow for access in the same package for test code). But your idea goes way beyond that. So: don't waste your time working around the error.